# Camera-based Driver

Tags: python, scripting, camera, drivers

I noticed that making drivers is difficult for a lot who know python in Blender. I have absolutely no idea where I'm going with it, and need help please.

Goal:
I'm trying to achieve this ability with drivers:
https://youtu.be/srXAef8Eisg Notice

- I notice it has what I call the "feedback loop", where if you move the object and/or rotate the camera, the value where the driver is located will trigger and automatically slide back and forth 0.0 to 1.0). It's similar to camshapematic, but that addon has too many limitations. What I'm looking for can be achieve with drivers alone.
- Naturally, this would have the ability to work with values in general (node values, shapekeys, custom properties).
- Their next video touches on it a bit: https://youtu.be/gqm9-79RbOM but I don't know what's happening. if it's possible, can someone send me a .blend file over what's possibly going on?
- - My best guess is that the driver is on the scale, and influenced by the color change to determine what's being scaled between 0.0 and 1.0.
- And I'm assuming the setup in the video is registering both rotation/angle and [orbital rather than distance, if that exist?] location between the cone of the camera and the cone of the object's parented empty?
- And lastly, how would I include the piecewise function? I'm just learning what it is.

Here's what I was able to make with some help on using a driver with a piecewise function (it doesn't work in Blender 3.6. This isn't the driver I'm hoping to use of course. It's just an example):

```
 Object.PropValue = max(min(any((Sun.rotation.quaternion- (Object.matrix_world * vertex)).dot(normal) > 0 for vertex, normal in zip(Object.data.vertices, Object.data.normals))) * (1 if 0.2 <= dot_product <= 0.3 else 0.5), 0.4, 0.1)
```

- Essentially, an arm's rotation to and from the sun [or camera], affects a custom property, but it has a piecewise function [0.0 - 0.2 slow + 0.21 to 0.4 fast + 0.41 to 1.0 slow], so that the custom property [PropValue] has a stylized "pop" effect when sliding up and down the value based on the camera's angle. I wanted to add in stepped in 2s, but just couldn't imagine where to include it.
- The vertex normal and dot product stuff can be ignored. I realized it won't work because it won't stay 0.0 if facing away from the cam/light, and still turn the value to 1.0. But it did give me the idea that the more front-side of the vertex normals visible to the camera the closer it reaches to 1.0 automatically.
- The videos above do better justice with those custom wires on an empty they're using, which I can assume help the camera detect their specified xyz quaternion angles? Since spinning them around or the cam around I would assume won't gimbal lock?

I'm still learning. So be delicate lol. Would be tremendous help if someone can send me a .blend file for me to study over.

---

EDIT: Found this. The person who made the videos above. Here's their post on twitter about the cone driver with screenshots commented: https://twitter.com/tjf_kuroko/status/1441673834428440580
It's a little confusing for me to understand what I'm seeing here, sadly.

Comment: Hello @Marquis, I think this question would be clearer by starting off with a simple statement of the result you want to achieve. Maybe a specific example of a method you'd like to use more generally. Your last example seems to indicate something like "drive shape-keys by viewing angle" for toon or non-physical alteration of  the 2D shapes in view  projection? I can't be sure.

Comment: This is the best I can do, sorry. I can't really imagine a way to make simpler in explanation. Pretty much what you see in the videos I linked is what I'm looking for, plus a piecewise "slide-skip-slide" effect. The details provided is to avoid confusion since I was told I need to be thorough. So I spent a long time typing this up lol. Each bulletin hits each issue necessary to get the whole picture... I stated that the example code is to get a point of view of the piecewise function but I'm not clear if it really works this way.